# Find logical flaws or inefficiencies in code

Tags: c++, logic

I study c++ and I have an exercise like this:

Find logical flaws or inefficiencies in this code.

I found out that two for statements are inefficient.
But I feel that more problem points exist.
Help me find out where they are.

```
int Sum(int start, int last) {
 int* a = new int[last - start];
 int sum = 0;

 for (int i = start; i <= last; ++i) {
     a[i] = i;
 }

 for (int i = start; i <= last; ++i) {
     sum += a[i];
 }
 return sum;
}
```

Comment: You couldn't come up with a single flaw in the code yourself?  The very first line in that function has an issue.  What if `last` is 1 and start is `10000`?

Comment: Please don't delegate your homework to Stack Overflow without showing any of your own efforts.

Answer (score 0):

This code has multiple coding problems:

- It allocates a new array, but never frees it (a memory leak)
- It does not allocate enough memory for the array (`last - start` should be `last - start + 1`)
- It indexes the array from `start` to `last`, inclusive, when it should be indexing it from 0 to `last - start`, inclusive
- When `last` is less than `start` the call of `new []` has undefined behavior (no precondition check).

However, the biggest problem is the logical one: the code computes the sum of consecutive numbers between `start` and `last`, inclusive, which can be done in closed form with the formula for the sum of [*arithmetic progression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum), which does not use an array at all:

```
int Sum(int start, int last) {
    return (last - start + 1)*(last + start) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Is the array needed at all?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  No, it is not necessary for closed-form computation.